# Why does an io.reader become empty after reading it?

Tags: go, io

```
func foo(buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    fmt.Println("0: ", len(buf.Bytes()))
    ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    fmt.Println("1: ", len(buf.Bytes()))
}
```

The code shows the correct length the first time, but the second times it shows the length is zero.

Answer (score 10):

Reading from a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) drains or consumes the bytes that were read. This means if you try to read again, those will not be returned.

[`Buffer.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes) returns the **unread** portion of the buffer, so it is the expected result for you to see `0` length after everything has been read (this is exactly what [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) does).

---

What if you just want to "peek" and not really "read" bytes?

There is no "peek" functionality in `bytes.Buffer`. The easiest would be to get the bytes of the buffer, and construct another `bytes.Buffer` from it and read from the new buffer.

It could look something like this:

```
func peek(buf *bytes.Buffer, b []byte) (int, error) {
    buf2 := bytes.NewBuffer(buf.Bytes())
    return buf2.Read(b)
}
```

#### `peek()` in action:

Error checks omitted for simplicity:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

buf.WriteString("Hello")
fmt.Printf("Len: %d, Content: %s\n", buf.Len(), buf)

fmt.Println("\nPeeking...")
data := make([]byte, 4)
peek(buf, data)
fmt.Printf("Peeked: %s\n", data)
fmt.Printf("Len: %d, Content: %s\n", buf.Len(), buf)

fmt.Println("\nReading...")
data = make([]byte, buf.Len())
buf.Read(data)
fmt.Printf("Read: %s\n", data)
fmt.Printf("Len: %d, Content: %s\n", buf.Len(), buf)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mI-nhmdtH4)):

```
Len: 5, Content: Hello

Peeking...
Peeked: Hell
Len: 5, Content: Hello

Reading...
Read: Hello
Len: 0, Content:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand. And Does has any ways that read its content second times?

Comment: This approach doesn't copy anything (other than data in to b), just creates a new buffer.  Only way I can see this being faster is to do "return copy(buf.Bytes(),b),nil"  which has the same effect but doesn't allocate a new buffer.  not sure which is actually faster.  (guessing the copy is)

Comment: @DavidBudworth Yeah, you're right. `Buffer.Bytes()` just returns a slice sharing the same underlying array. So it's not bad performance-wise at all.

Comment: Seems like there be problems using this approach for network buffers that probably don't have all the data in `Buffer.Bytes()` yet.

Comment: @Xeoncross `bytes.Buffer` is an in-memory buffer, it has nothing to do with networking. In case of a network, we have to take care of "replaying" the data read and inspected. An example can be found in this answer: [Golang read request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021058/golang-read-request-body/43021236#43021236)