# Golang read request body multiple times

Tags: http, go, server

I am writing my own logginMiddleware. Basically, I need to log body of the request and the response. The problem that I faced is that when I read body, it becomes empty and I cannot read it twice. 
I understand that it happens because it is of type ReadCloser. Is there a way to rewind body to the beginning?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

#### Inspecting and mocking request body

When you first read the body, you have to store it so once you're done with it, you can set a new [`io.ReadCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser) as the request body constructed from the original data. So when you advance in the chain, the next handler can read the same body.

One option is to read the whole body using [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll), which gives you the body as a byte slice.

You may use [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) to obtain an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) from a byte slice.

The last missing piece is to make the `io.Reader` an `io.ReadCloser`, because `bytes.Buffer` does not have a `Close()` method. For this you may use [`ioutil.NopCloser()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) which wraps an `io.Reader`, and returns an `io.ReadCloser`, whose added `Close()` method will be a no-op (does nothing).

Note that you may even modify the contents of the byte slice you use to create the "new" body. You have full control over it.

<sup>Care must be taken though, as there might be other HTTP fields like content-length and checksums which may become invalid if you modify only the data. If subsequent handlers check those, you would also need to modify those too!</sup>

#### Inspecting / modifying response body

If you also want to read the response body, then you have to wrap the [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) you get, and pass the wrapper on the chain. This wrapper may cache the data sent out, which you can inspect either after, on on-the-fly (as the subsequent handlers write to it).

Here's a simple `ResponseWriter` wrapper, which just caches the data, so it'll be available after the subsequent handler returns:

```
type MyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    buf *bytes.Buffer
}

func (mrw *MyResponseWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return mrw.buf.Write(p)
}
```

Note that `MyResponseWriter.Write()` just writes the data to a buffer. You may also choose to inspect it on-the-fly (in the `Write()` method) and write the data immediately to the wrapped / embedded `ResponseWriter`. You may even modify the data. You have full control.

<sup>Care must be taken again though, as the subsequent handlers may also send HTTP response headers related to the response data –such as length or checksums– which may also become invalid if you alter the response data.</sup>

#### Full example

Putting the pieces together, here's a full working example:

```
func loginmw(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error reading body: %v", err)
            http.Error(w, "can't read body", http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        // Work / inspect body. You may even modify it!

        // And now set a new body, which will simulate the same data we read:
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))

        // Create a response wrapper:
        mrw := &MyResponseWriter{
            ResponseWriter: w,
            buf:            &bytes.Buffer{},
        }

        // Call next handler, passing the response wrapper:
        handler.ServeHTTP(mrw, r)

        // Now inspect response, and finally send it out:
        // (You can also modify it before sending it out!)
        if _, err := io.Copy(w, mrw.buf); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send out response: %v", err)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you still want to close the initial body before reassigning it?

Comment: @Jeff The request body does not need to be closed by the handler, it is closed by the server. See [Where to put “defer req.Body.Close()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525499/where-to-put-defer-req-body-close/42533540#42533540)

Comment: You should limit the amount you read from the body, otherwise it's just a DoS vector. Please use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader @icza

Comment: @sztanpet Yes, there are even more considerations, the answer is just the theory how inspecting the request and response bodies can be achieved. Protecting against malicious large request should be handled at the top level, not in every intermediate handler.

Comment: `ioutil.ReadAll` is not recommended for http request body handling, especially for high loads servers. See: https://haisum.github.io/2017/09/11/golang-ioutil-readall/

Comment: @icza I did not get this in your answer: "You may use `bytes.NewBuffer()` to obtain an `io.Reader` from a byte slice."  Because... `bytes.NewBuffer(buf)` creates and initializes a new Buffer using `buf`([]byte) as its initial contents... Are you saying that, `bytes.Buffer` is `io.Reader` & `io.Writer`?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, `bytes.Buffer` is both `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`. If you pass a slice to it, you can use it to read from that slice.

Comment: I have been using this approach. However my buf becomes polluted with other encoded data which could be related to the checksums/headers @icza mentions. In longer requests I get completely unreadable data, which could be related with compression. How can can you deal with this data if you want to log it? Do you attempt to encoded and clean it?

Answer (score 2):

I could use the `GetBody` from Request package.

Look this comment in source code from [request.go](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) in net/http:

> GetBody defines an optional func to return a new copy of
>   Body. It is used for client requests when a redirect requires
>   reading the body more than once. Use of GetBody still
>   requires setting Body.
>   For server requests it is unused."

`GetBody func() (io.ReadCloser, error)`

This way you can get the body request without make it empty.

Sample:

```
getBody := request.GetBody
copyBody, err := getBody()
if err != nil {
    // Do something return err
}
http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```

Comment: ** For server requests it is unused **, you can get the body from server side for copy purpose, or a panic `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` will happen

Comment: Hi @seanlook, my mistake.
You need to check the error returned by getBody()

`getBody := request.GetBody
copyBody, err := getBody()

if err != nil {
    // Do something
    return err
}

http.DefaultClient.Do(request)`

Comment: with golang 1.4 the func GetBody returns a nil, then copyBody fires an error

Comment: AFAIK, GetBody() isn't a function to use, but rather a function to define, isn't it? Well, according to docs, it's an optional field in the Request struct, which may be filled with a user code. And only then used. Not the other way around.