# How to log the HTTP return code with the chi router?

Tags: go, logging, return-code, go-chi

I use [`chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) as my router and wrote a simple middleware that logs the request being made:

```
func logCalls(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Info().Msgf("%v → %v", r.URL, r.RemoteAddr)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

It works great but I am missing the HTTP return code.

The HTTP return code will obviously be available once all the routes are exhausted but at the same time I have to use my middleware before the routes.

Is there a way to hook it after the routing is done, and therefore have the return code I can log?

Comment: #1 To log something *after* the handler's done you can simply put the log statement below the `next.ServerHTTP(w, r)` call, instead of above. Or use a `defer` if you want to ensure that the log is made even in a case where the handler panics.

Comment: #2 To be able to get access to the status code however you'll need to wrap the `w` response writer into a custom implementation, one that records the status code and gives you access to it. For an example of how to do that, you can take a look at this answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528234/log-http-responsewriter-content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NewWrapResponseWriter](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/middleware/logger.go#L48) worked for me:

```
import "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"

func logCalls(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ww := middleware.NewWrapResponseWriter(w, r.ProtoMajor)
        next.ServeHTTP(ww, r)
        log.Info().Msgf("%v → %v %v", r.URL, r.RemoteAddr, ww.Status())
        
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `render` from go-chi library.
https://github.com/go-chi/render/tree/v1.0.1

Example of usage is here:
https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/_examples/rest/main.go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).