# How to reuse request body of *http.Request between HTTP middleware handlers?

Tags: http, go, middleware

I use go-chi as HTTP-router, and I want to reuse one method inside another

```
func Registration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // if you delete this line, the user will be created   
    // ...other code

    // if all good then create new user
    user.Create(w, r)
}

...

func Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)  
  // ...other code

  // ... there I get the problem with parse JSON from &b
}
```

`user.Create` return error `"unexpected end of JSON input"`

Actually, after I executed `ioutil.ReadAll`
`user.Create` ceased to parse JSON,
in `r.Body` there was an empty array`[]`how can I fix this problem?

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47558164/720999).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I was able to recover data in this way:

```
r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(b))
```

Comment: I think it is necessary to call r.Body.Close() before this line

Answer (score 9):

The outer handler reads the request body to EOF. When the inner handler is called, there's nothing more to read from the body.

To fix the issue, restore the request body with the data read previously in the outer handler:

```
func Registration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) 
    // ...other code
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b))
    user.Create(w, r)
}
```

The function `bytes.NewReader()` returns a `io.Reader` on a byte slice.  The function `ioutil.NopCloser` converts an `io.Reader` to the `io.ReadCloser` required for `r.Body`.