# Json body is nil after Middleware

Tags: go, go-gin

So i have these routes:

```
    setpw := api.Group("/user/pw")
    setpw.Use(middlewares.OTPMiddleware())

    setpw.POST("/set", controllers.SetPassword)
```

in the OTPMiddleware i am just checking if the OTP is valid, after that i am using context.Next() to go to the controllers.SetPassword. But my context Body is somehow nil why?

```
func OTPMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var phonedb models.PhoneToken

        // PARSE JSON BODY TO PHONE MODEL
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&phonedb); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"head": "error", "body": err.Error()})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }
        //SOME LOGIC HERE
    //Go to next handler
    c.Next()
    }
}
```

This is my SetPassword

```
func SetPassword(c *gin.Context) {

    log.Println("Request Body:", c.Request.Body)
    var setpw models.SetPassword
    // BIND JSON TO EMAIL MODEL
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&setpw); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"head": "error", "body": "Parsing failed"})
        return
    }
```

My Error Message:

```
Request Body: &{0xc0006d4990 <nil> <nil> true true {0 0} true false false 0x6ead20}
```

Comment: Well, reading a stream will exhaust it. You need to process a copy of it.

Comment: So you mean if i parse the context to JSON then the context becomes null?

Comment: How can i make a copy and pass it after consum?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021058/golang-read-request-body-multiple-times or many of the duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang read request body multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021058/golang-read-request-body-multiple-times)

Comment: well i am struggling but i am trying.