# Decoding JSON data from HttpWriter response data that comes compressed or has extra information

Tags: json, go, encoding, middleware, httpresponse

I am wrapping the RequestWriter as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021058/golang-read-request-body-multiple-times/43021236#43021236)

```
type MyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    buf *bytes.Buffer
}

func (mrw *MyResponseWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return mrw.buf.Write(p)
}
```

However my buffer `buf` becomes polluted with other encoded data which could be related to the checksums/headers @icza mentions. In longer requests I get completely unreadable data, which could be related with compression. How can can you deal with this data if you want to parse it into a json for logging purposes for example?

Here are a couple of snapshots of what I get if I try to log buf.String()

[image: longer json]

[image: shorter json]

Comment: thanks @CeriseLimón, I dug a bit deeper and found out that I had a gzip Middleware running to compress the api response. I moved that middleware upward so that it wrapped my logging middleware and not the other way around, that solved the problem.